# why cant I pass interface in kotlin sometimes?

Tags: kotlin

I've just started to learn kotlin and currently reading the generated code from Android Studio. I've noticed that I can do something like

```
view.setOnClickListener { callAnotherMethod() }
```

so I've created a test interface

```
interface TestListener {
    fun onTest()
}
```

and a `fun` to set listener

```
private fun setTest(listener: TestListener) {

}
```

but at this time calling `setTest{ callAnotherMethod() }` wont work. I don't understand why. `setOnClickedListener()` is asking for an interface and so does `setTest`. At the same time, `OnClickListener` is an interface and so does `TestListener`. Why am I not able to do the same with `TestListener`?

Comment: SAM conversion is only for Java methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try it this:

```
test(object : TestListener {

override fun onTest() {

}
})
```

Or use it:

```
val aTestListner = object : TestListener {
    override fun onTest() {
}
}TestListener
```